How to hide or disable thee "sort by" input and label for the vuetify 3 <v-data-table> on mobile view
I am using a vuetify <v-data-table> to show some data :
Mobile View:

Code:
<v-data-table-server
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage" 
    :headers="headers"
    :items="serverItems" 
    :items-length="totalItems" 
    :loading="loading" 
    :search="search"
    item-value="id" 
    fixed-header
    no-data-text="Sin datos"
    @update:options="loadItems" 
    items-per-page-text="autos por página" loading-text="obteniendo datos..."
>

The columns :
headers: [
    { title: 'Patente', key: 'patente', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Marca', key: 'marca', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Modelo', key: 'modelo', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Precio', key: 'precio', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Caja', key: 'caja', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Combustible', key: 'combustible', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Pasajeros', key: 'pasajeros', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Descripcion', key: 'descripcion', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Foto', key: 'fotos', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Opciones', key: 'options', sortable: false }
]

I tried setting the columns property sortable to false but it didn't help.

Can't you use CSS media queries? If below a specific viewport, display: none; the elements you do not want.

Haven't found any methods besides the CSS solution.
.v-data-table-headers--mobile {
  display: none;
}

Or if you don't want the table to be responsive on mobile, you can do the following:
<v-data-table-server
...
mobile-breakpoint="0">


Sounds like it yes.
